# Constructing a vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that subordinate matrix norm equals the spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Statement of problem: "Let $A$ be square diagonalizable matrix. Constructing a vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that subordinate matrix norm, $||A||=\max|\lambda_i|$"

I know that $A$ being square diagonalizable $\implies A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is invertible and $D$ is diagonal. What does this have to do with the problem? I can't see the connection

I guess my question is, what does it mean when they say to construct a vector norm?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a norm $\|\cdot\|$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can construct a matrix norm (in the space of linear operators from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$), which is given by
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|.
$$

You are being asked to find a norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that

$$
\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \max|\lambda_i|.
$$

*note:* You may want to check the Euclidean norm.

Comment: I just found this definition: the matrix norm $||\cdot||$ is subordinate to vector norm $||\cdot||_*$ if $||Ax||_*\leq||A||||x||_*$. Is this valid in this case?

Comment: @user5896534 If you are able to prove that $\|A\| = \sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{\| A x\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$ you have that, in particular, $\|A\| \ge \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$.